# from which branch the remote branch is created

Tags: git, branch, gitlab

I have `develop` branch on my local.Its created using `remote develop` branch.

Now I want to know from which `other remote branch` this `remote develop branch` is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log` with flags you can see parent branch or branch topology.

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --all --graph
```

Possibly duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6456546/4133798)